# Creación anidada de recursos en WebApi

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

mi problema es el siguiente.

Tengo un cliente y ese cliente puede tener uno o varios domicilios y uno o varios telefonos. Como haría para crear los otros recursos mediante la misma request de creación de cliente?.

Supongo que la request seria algo asi.

```
{
  "Nombre":"Franco",
  "Apellido":"Pachue",
  "DNI":88888888,
  "Domicilios":[{"Calle":"Falsa","Numero":123}]
  "Telefonos":[{"Numero":88888888}]
}
```

Pero al controller llega como nulo el Dto si incluyo los datos de domicilio y telefono. Si solo paso Nombre, Apellido y DNI me lo crea.

```
    public class ClientesController : Controller
{
    private IClienteService _clienteService;
    private IMapper _mapper;
    private readonly AppSettings _appSettings;

    public ClientesController(
        IClienteService clienteService,
        IMapper mapper,
        IOptions<AppSettings> appSettings)
    {
        _clienteService = clienteService;
        _mapper = mapper;
        _appSettings = appSettings.Value;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Create([FromBody]ClienteDto clienteDto)
    {

        var cliente = _mapper.Map<Cliente>(clienteDto);

        try
        {

            _clienteService.Create(cliente);
            return Ok();
        }
        catch (AppException ex)
        {

            return BadRequest(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Este es mi controlador cliente con el metodo create.

```
        public Cliente Create(Cliente cliente)
    {
        if (_context.Clientes.Any(x => x.DNI == cliente.DNI))
            throw new AppException("DNI " + cliente.DNI + " ya en uso");


        _context.Clientes.Add(cliente);
        _context.SaveChanges();

        return cliente;
    }
```

Este es el método en mi ClienteService

```
public class Cliente
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
    public string Apellido { get; set; }
    public int DNI { get; set; }
    public List<Domicilio> Domicilios { get; set; }
    public List<Telefono> Telefonos { get; set; }
}
```

Y esta es mi entidad.

```
    public class ClienteDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
    public string Apellido { get; set; }
    public int DNI { get; set; }
    public List<Domicilio> Domicilios { get; set; }
    public List<Telefono> Telefonos { get; set; }
}
```

Este es el Dto por ahora es el mismo, lo hice por si necesito mas adelante alguna otra aplicación.

EDIT:

Si veo que tengo algún problema en el código, cambie los controladores para probar sin pasar por el servicio, use el scaffolding de net core para web api, y veo que me llega la request cortada.

Me llega este json

```
{"id":1,"nombre":"asdasd","apellido":"asdasd","dni":188888888,"domicilios":[{"id":2
```

Tirando la request a mi /api/clientes/1

```
        // GET: api/Clientes/5
    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetCliente([FromRoute] int id)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        var cliente = await _context.Clientes.SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id);
        cliente.Domicilios = _context.Domicilios.Where(c => c.Cliente.Id == cliente.Id).ToList();
        if (cliente == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return Ok(cliente);
    }
```

Asi que no puedo resolver bien como es la request que debería hacer.

El problema del get era que tenia mi entidad domicilios con un objeto cliente y mi entidad cliente con una lista de domicilios, entonces generaba una recursion.

Ahora el problema que tengo es una sql exception al querer guardar los datos del update

SqlException: Sintaxis incorrecta cerca de 'MERGE'.

En el create

```
        public Cliente Create(Cliente cliente)
    {
        if (_context.Clientes.Any(x => x.DNI == cliente.DNI))
            throw new AppException("Username " + cliente.DNI + " is already taken");


        _context.Clientes.Add(cliente);
        _context.Domicilios.AddRange(cliente.Domicilios);
        _context.SaveChanges();

        return cliente;
    }
```

Comment: Usa un `foreach`  para insertar cada elemento de los domicilios y de teléfonos en el método `Create` del `Cliente`

Comment: El tema es que me llega nulo el Dto, supongo que no lo puede mapear si llega así la request , si la request viene con nombre apellido y DNI solamente me lo crea

Comment: Bueno, entonces la pregunta va enfocada a que la información llega nula al Controller. Sería bueno que la edites para que quedara un poco más clara ;)

Comment: Estaras mandando mal el request? como lo estas construyendo? "Domicilios":[{"Calle":"Falsa","Numero":123}] esta construccion con corchetes me suena rara

Comment: Los puedo sacar a los corchetes, es porque puedo tener mas de un domicilio, lo armaría como array. Pero sin corchetes estaría pasando lo mismo. Ahora lo estoy armando a mano para probar.

Comment: falta la definición de ClienteDto. Llega un valor nulo, o sólo las colecciones vienen en blanco?

Comment: Ahi agregue el Dto, viene el valor nulo, asi que supongo que estoy armando mal la request, si paso solo nombre apellido y dni, viene bien. .

Comment: Se sugiero probar tu servicio con [Insomnia](https://insomnia.rest/) o [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/), para que puedas probar el caso "ideal", y después revisar qué envía tu cliente usando algo como [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) o [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) para capturar el tráfico de red.

Comment: Yo probaria como te llega quitando los domicilios y los telefonos, para asegurar que el problema no viene del ModelBinder para esas entidades.
Los `[ ]` estan bien si representan un array en el json

Comment: Si, los post sin domicilio me funcionan bien, el tema es como crear mi cliente y anidar la creacion del domicilio, lo mismo con un get buscar un cliente y anidar la busqueda del domicilio y asi con todos los verbos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entity Framework Core me genera la creación anidada por su cuenta solo debo pasar el json entero. También cambie el modelo de Domicilios para que no me genere esa recursion.

```
{
"nombre": "Franco",
"apellido": "Pachue",
"dni": 365461,
"domicilios": [
    {
        "calle": "larrechea",
        "numero": 965
    },
    {
        "calle": "larrechea",
        "numero": 965
    }
],
"telefonos": []
```

}

Con una request de este tipo y con el create de mi servicio, ya se genera mis domicilios y mi cliente sin necesidad de deserializar ni nada parecido.

Otro problema que existia, es que EF Core es compatible con SQL 2008+ y yo tenía una base 2005 por lo tanto se generaba una sintaxis que no existía para mi base.Le hice un update a la versión 2017.

Al momento de hacer los GET debido a lazy load debo incluir los domicilios en la carga.

Por ejemplo:

```
return _context.Clientes.Include(c=>c.Domicilios).Include(c=> c.Telefonos);
```

Y para uno en particular:

```
        public Cliente GetById(int id)
    {

        return _context.Clientes.Include(c=>c.Domicilios).Include(c=>c.Telefonos).FirstOrDefault(c=>c.IdCliente == id); 
    }
```